# SQL Query on partitioning does not run

Tags: window-functions

When I run the following SQL command

```
select payee_id, start_dt, 
       row_number() over(partition by payee_id order by start_dt) as rn 
from xxx 
where rn = 1
```

I got an error :

> error Invalid identifier 'rn'

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rn` cannot be referenced in `WHERE` because it's defined in the `SELECT` clause. Try using a subquery instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select payee_id,start_dt,
           row_number() over(partition by payee_id order by start_dt) as rn
    from xxx
) AS sub
where rn = 1;
```

For more reading, google "logical query processing order".